# Django deploy on FastCGI ImportError: no module named wagtailcore

Tags: django, module, importerror, wagtail

I know there's been alot of Django ImportErrors answered but I've tried all their solutions to no avail!

Background: I'm trying to setup Wagtail (Django variant) on a shared hosting with A Small Orange. Due to ASO specifications, I run python 2.6 + virtualenv + FastCGI

my project directory is in:

```
~/username/website/wagtailweb
```

my pip_installed packages and all relevant symblinks are in:

```
~/.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages
```

When I visit my domain I get Django's Import Error at /
Traceback:

```
    Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://username.co/

Django Version: 1.6.2
Python Version: 2.6.6
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'south',
 'compressor',
 'taggit',
 'modelcluster',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailcore',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailadmin',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtaildocs',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailsnippets',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailusers',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailimages',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailembeds',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailsearch',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailredirects',
 'tutorial')

Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailcore.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
 'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailredirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/home/username/.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/home/username/.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  320.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/home/username/.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  320.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/home/username/.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  222.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/home/username/.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  229.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/home/username/.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  32.         result = func(*args)
File "/home/username/.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  100.                     not module_has_submodule(import_module(parentmod), submod)):
File "/home/username/.env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  41.         __import__(name)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named wagtailcore
```

my settings.py

```
# Django settings for wagtailweb project.

import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', '..')

DEBUG = True
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

ADMINS = ()
MANAGERS = ADMINS

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': PROJECT_ROOT+'/wagtailweb.db',
        'HOST': '',  # Set to empty string for localhost.
        'PORT': '',  # Set to empty string for default.
    }
}

CONN_MAX_AGE = 600  # number of seconds database connections should persist for
ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
TIME_ZONE = 'Europe/London'
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-gb'
SITE_ID = 1
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = False
USE_TZ = True
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = ()

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailcore.middleware.SiteMiddleware',
    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailredirects.middleware.RedirectMiddleware',
)

from django.conf import global_settings
TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = global_settings.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    'django.core.context_processors.request',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'wagtailweb.urls'
TEMPLATE_DIRS = ()

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    # 'django.contrib.sites',  # Wagtail uses its own site management logic
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'south',
    'compressor',
    'taggit',
    'modelcluster',
    'django.contrib.admin',

    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailcore',
    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailadmin',
    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtaildocs',
    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailsnippets',
    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailusers',
    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailimages',
    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailembeds',
    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailsearch',
    'wagtail.wagtail.wagtailredirects',

    'tutorial',
)

EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX = '[wagtailweb] '

INTERNAL_IPS = ('127.0.0.1', '10.0.2.2')

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
)

# Auth settings
LOGIN_URL = 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'wagtailadmin_home'

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}


# WAGTAIL SETTINGS
WAGTAIL_SITE_NAME = 'wagtailweb'

# Override the search results template for wagtailsearch
WAGTAILSEARCH_RESULTS_TEMPLATE = 'tutorial/search_results.html'
WAGTAILSEARCH_RESULTS_TEMPLATE_AJAX = 'tutorial/includes/search_listing.html'

WAGTAILSEARCH_ES_INDEX = 'wagtailweb'
```

my urls.py

```
import os
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.views.generic.base import RedirectView
from django.contrib import admin
from django.conf import settings

from wagtail.wagtail.wagtailcore import urls as wagtail_urls
from wagtail.wagtail.wagtailadmin import urls as wagtailadmin_urls
from wagtail.wagtail.wagtailimages import urls as wagtailimages_urls
from wagtail.wagtail.wagtailembeds import urls as wagtailembeds_urls
from wagtail.wagtail.wagtaildocs import admin_urls as wagtaildocs_admin_urls
from wagtail.wagtail.wagtaildocs import urls as wagtaildocs_urls
from wagtail.wagtail.wagtailsnippets import urls as wagtailsnippets_urls
from wagtail.wagtail.wagtailsearch.urls import frontend as wagtailsearch_frontend_urls, admin as wagtailsearch_admin_urls
from wagtail.wagtail.wagtailusers import urls as wagtailusers_urls
from wagtail.wagtail.wagtailredirects import urls as wagtailredirects_urls

admin.autodiscover()


# Signal handlers
from wagtail.wagtail.wagtailsearch import register_signal_handlers as wagtailsearch_register_signal_handlers
wagtailsearch_register_signal_handlers()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^django-admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^admin/images/', include(wagtailimages_urls)),
    url(r'^admin/embeds/', include(wagtailembeds_urls)),
    url(r'^admin/documents/', include(wagtaildocs_admin_urls)),
    url(r'^admin/snippets/', include(wagtailsnippets_urls)),
    url(r'^admin/search/', include(wagtailsearch_admin_urls)),
    url(r'^admin/users/', include(wagtailusers_urls)),
    url(r'^admin/redirects/', include(wagtailredirects_urls)),
    url(r'^admin/', include(wagtailadmin_urls)),
    url(r'^search/', include(wagtailsearch_frontend_urls)),
    url(r'^documents/', include(wagtaildocs_urls)),

    # For anything not caught by a more specific rule above, hand over to
    # Wagtail's serving mechanism
    url(r'', include(wagtail_urls)),
)


if settings.DEBUG:
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns() # tell gunicorn where static files are in dev mode
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL + 'images/', document_root=os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'images'))
```

Wagtailcore is a module within the Wagtail app I've installed. It does have it's own init.py and is on the python sys path.

All of the tracebacks lead to Django and I'm reluctant to fiddle with their code. It must be something from my end, but unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable enough to figure out what is causing it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue may be related to the fact you're using Python 2.6.  Django 1.7 (which Wagtail requires) does not support Python 2.6, only Python 2.7 and higher. Hope that helps!